# ipad landscape/ portrait image

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape, portrait

I am working on UI issue of ipad app development (about image). I have read some documents on apple development site but i cannot find any information about it.

Is there any file convention for image files to distinguish which image the system should load for Landscape/Portrait. Because I see that for launching image, we can use "MyLaunchImage-Portrait.png" & "MyLaunchImage-Lanscape.png". I have tried to add "-Landscape", "-Portrait", "-Landscape~ipad", "-Portrait~ipad" to other images for general use but it fails.

Is there anyone who has encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not standard convention for this other than the iPad's launch images. However, you can use `NSNotificationCenter` to listen for orientation change events and respond to them accordingly. Here's an example:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //isShowingLandscapeView should be a BOOL declared in your header (.h)
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myLandscapeImage"]];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
             isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPortraitImage"]];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way i am using, do not have to use notification center to detect orientation change :  - (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    
}